# Retrieve inferred string literal from object keys

Tags: node.js, typescript, types

I'm trying to create a type that defines the value based on the key. If the key extends `$${string}` (e.g. `$foo`) the value should be the key without the prefix e.g. `foo`. If the key doens't extend `$${string}` (e.g. `boo`) the values should be `null`.

**Example**

```js
const example = {
  $foo: 'foo',
  boo: null,
}
```

Here is an isolated example I created to get it done - but it doesn't work as intended when I apply it to the code below.

```js
type Value<T> = T extends `$${infer I}` ? I : null

type ExampleA = Value<'$foo'> // type is 'foo' 
type ExampleB = Value<'boo'>  // type is null
```

**My current code**

```js
type Values = {
    [K in string]: K extends `$${infer p}` ? p : null;
}

const values = {
    $foo: 'foo', // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'null'.
    foo: null,
    
    $boo: 'boo', // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'null'.
    boo: null,
} satisfies Values;

type Expected = {
    readonly $foo: 'foo',
    readonly foo: null,
    
    readonly $boo: 'boo',
    readonly boo: null,
}
```

**The `satisfies Values` is used to infer the type later on. Similar approach is acceptable**

Thanks for your help and time - cheers

Comment: Please explain why `satisfies Values` is "mandatory".  There is no specific `Values` type in TypeScript which meets your needs, so if you literally have to write `satisfies Values` then what you want is either impossible, or the `satisfies Values` part will not be doing anything useful.  For example, [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WG4aVw) is what I'd probably do here, but since `satisfies Values` is not literally present, I guess it doesn't help you.  So how should we proceed?  Do you want to see "this is not possible" or "this is possible if you relax your constraint"?

Comment: Hi @jcalz - The reason why `satisfies Values` is mandatory is due to the way it is inffered later. But this is also achived by using a function like your solution - havn't though of that  Although this leaves me with new issues due to the simplification of the examples above - that's on me Hopefully you saved me again - Thanks

Comment: So then I will write up an answer proposing the `satisfiesValues` function approach.  Meanwhile you might want to [edit] the question clarifying that what you need is for the type of `values` to be checked for correctness without being widened, such as the kind of behavior you get with the `satisfies` operator... without going so far as to say that `satisfies` is mandatory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your `Values` type is that [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `string` do not behave the way you expect them to.  While *conceptually* you can think of `string` as the infinite [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of all possible string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), a mapped type over `string` does not even try to iterate over every possible string literal type; it just maps one thing: `string`:

```
type Values = {
  [K in string]: K extends `\$${infer S}` ? S : null;
}
/* type Values = {
    [x: string]: null;
} */
```

And since `string` does not extend `` `\$${infer S}` ``, then the property type for the `string` key is `null`.

This is working as intended, as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#22509](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22509).  Mapped types over `string` are not what you want.

---

And unfortunately there is no way to write a specific type in TypeScript which behaves the way you want.  The closest you could get is something like

```
type Values = {
  [k: `\$${string}`]: string;
  [k: string]: string | null;
}
```

using a [template string pattern index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#symbol-and-template-string-pattern-index-signatures), but the parts where the property value string needs to match the part after the `"$"` character (not just `string`) and the part where other keys need to have a `null` (not just `string | null`) cannot be represented:

```
const values = {
  $foo: 'foo',
  foo: null,
  $boo: 'boo',
  boo: null,
  $oops: null, // error, not string
  oops: 'hmm', // should be error, but isn't!
  $whoops: 'oops', // should be error, but isn't!
} satisfies Values;
```

So we have to give up on the approach using [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator), because there is no appropriate `Values` type to use it with.

---

What you really care about is having the type of `values` inferred by the compiler but still checked against your desired constraint.  We can get behavior like this by replacing `satisfies Values` with a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) helper function we can call `satisfiesValues()`.  At runtime this function just returns its input, but the compiler can use it to validate the object literal passed in.  So instead of `const values = {...} satisfies Values;` you would write `const values = satisfiesValues({...});`.

Here's one possible implementation:

```
const satisfiesValues = <K extends PropertyKey>(
  val: { [P in K]: P extends `\$${infer S}` ? S : null }
) => val;
```

The function is generic in `K`, the keys of the `val` value passed in.  This will most likely be some union of known keys (none of which will be just `string`), and then the mapped type behaves as desired:

```
const values = satisfiesValues({
  $foo: 'foo',
  foo: null,
  $boo: 'boo',
  boo: null,
  $oops: null, // error, not "oops"
  oops: 'hmm', // error, not null
  $whoops: 'oops', // error, not "whoops"
});

/* const values: {
    foo: null;
    $foo: "foo";
    boo: null;
    $boo: "boo";
    oops: null;
    $whoops: "whoops";
    $oops: "oops";
} */
```

Looks good.  The type of `values` is what you want it to be, and the compiler allows the valid properties and complains about the invalid ones.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=false&ts=4.9.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEA5A9jZBvAsAKCSQBcBPTJANRABsBXaJAXiVwMKQG0BpJAS2CRQiAJ34BzALoAuJDwgAPIhGAATKEgAGAHQAkOrPwBmEYUgDKAXw1IA-OaQzgtatQDc+QhY9IA9ACpiMmQqOgZmVnZ2DnkZIVFgSUdnN28LJD8ffC88fFBIWARkAGFqNCgTACFaIjMiXhd0IgAlXjEACyIWfG9SchD6dXDvQg4AaxltPSw48StpQRFxdzYR8YX4xPXxJAAfJCcXZc9veDRgISQANxoBpi6VpB1DNDQZAHJntDeAGmGkT6SLl+Dx0ACMXu9wV9gZEoYDqDD2DoXjAoPDvr4fEgTMI0MIMcA0J0Zgk-ii0Ug3m0wGAfpjBG00M4VEhQcgcXiMaDqnwoMA3kQAIR-HQAd0ZGApb3JdJ8WKgjOZrPZwlx+NZPN4fIFwrYaSgIDqUEMvAY-Wgyyy3TweWgcEQSAA6njRupWCczhcDUaTdBzYMkAAeOSKZRqJAABVxmGEpC4EBIAD4ABR-a7UGRYTgRvgCLjzHMKJSqdSTfRGEzmKy2ezwpDZQgASiYiauNEtbFO5066duzG9Wt9UH9yYiSIBlM+Pz+E4OCJFcMpUOnD0Xc8RhGRkvR9I56sJnQAROTD2Tt5TqbSMXLsarOfsiftkiLxeT3jLr1i9wTH4fX5LTz1RsO0IfwkC7C5e2gTM-kIWdkiOSJHgnQ9PkPRDYQhJ9Dlgx5F0PKF0Nwt9sJSB5N3-VEZD-CVUSI8jHhI48AMQtIMmtCwgA)

Comment: ‍♂️ Mostly from reading the release notes, documentation, and github issues, and playing around with it a lot.

Comment: I got alot from this [repo](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges) shout out to the creators  Just read the release notes for 5.0 - the `const` sounds exiting - cheers